# Beta kit absent from fabric plugin

Tags: android-studio, plugins

I am trying to use Beta from fabric through their plugin on Android Studio, but I cannot find the kit. I can find a bunch of them, including crashlytic and Answer, which I use, but not Beta. The doc doesn't help to find it. Is it normal?

The plugin version is 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. My gradle wasn't in the correct version. It needed to be at least 1.5.0